# What does orIF mean in the middle of this Japanese sentence?

Tags: meaning, slang

I've seen some people in Japanese writing the emoticon "orlF".  For example:

> というシチュであったかもしれない**orlF**のストーリーという感じです

And I really want to know what it means... xDD. Please help~ ^^'

Comment: Could you provide a sentence where you saw it? It doesn't seem to be a popular one most people could understand...

Comment: @broccoliforest Sure, It was this one, I think: "というシチュであったかもしれないorlFのストーリーという感じです".

Comment: It's actually... two English words: "or" and "if". We use "or" when being too lazy to write its Japanese counterpart, and "IF" is a novel community jargon that means AU (alternative universe). No space between because they think they're writing Japanese.

Comment: Not to mention that I'm supposing it should be "**i**" instead of "**L**". Does everyone type "L"?

Comment: `"what-if" story` とも言います? (そんなに自信ないですけど)

Comment: 'Nuff comments; We need an answer.

Answer (score 2):

broccoli forest pretty much answered it in the comments.  The sentence example provided also is fairly self explanatory. It's "or" and "if" not separated by a space (and for some reason the "I" is a lower case "L").  The "or" really doesn't need to be there.

"If" by it itself is a common term used in parody short story writing, though I think it's still slang).  It means in English "alternate universe", "parallel universe",  "What-if world".  "If" stories can include the introduction of new characters, different events occurring, characters surviving where they originally died, and characters swapping genders.

Sometimes the Japanese equivalent 「もしも」 is used.  Also, it's commonly attached to other words to indicate it's referring to an alternate universe as opposed to the original story: IFストーリー、IFの世界, etc.